# What does this usage of ConvertTo-SecureString achieve?

Tags: powershell

What is the internal action of this power shell command

```
ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString;
```

Comment: What from the docs is unclear? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849818.aspx

Comment: I am writing code in linux and due to login to 0365 some one using poweshell code I am trying avoid it and do the same in java, so asked this question.

Comment: You will have to look at the docs for the java login method for O365.  The powershell credentials use a secure string.

Answer (score 2):

The actions in order:

1. Take the text `password` and convert it into an in-memory encrypted string of bytes
2. Serialize the SecureString into an encrypted string that can be saved to disk

A [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an in-memory encrypted representation of a string that is destroyed from memory as soon as it is no longer being used.

**Basically it is a way of encrypting a string that can then be stored on disk** without having to know much about all the various encryption utilities needed.

Comment: josh thank you for the reply what could be the encode for byte in power shell. I want to avoid power shell and do the same operation in java. can you help me with these details?

Answer (score 1):

Read the 2nd example of `get-help convertto-securestring` and yo uwill find the answer. Basically your command will encrypt the password and will be shown as encrypted text.

```
PS C:\> $secure = read-host -assecurestring
PS C:\>$secure
System.Security.SecureString
PS C:\>$encrypted = convertfrom-securestring -securestring $secure
PS C:\>$encrypted
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb010000001a114d45b8dd3f4aa11ad7c0abdae9800000000002000000000003660000a8000000100000005df63cea84bfb7d70bd6842e7
efa79820000000004800000a000000010000000f10cd0f4a99a8d5814d94e0687d7430b100000008bf11f1960158405b2779613e9352c6d14000000e6b7bf46a9d485ff211b9b2a2df3bd
6eb67aae41
PS C:\>$secure2 = convertto-securestring -string $encrypted
PS C:\>$secure2
System.Security.SecureString


This example shows how to create a secure string from user input, convert the secure string to an encrypted standard string, and then convert the encrypted standard string back 
to a secure string.

The first command uses the AsSecureString parameter of the Read-Host cmdlet to create a secure string. After you enter the command, any characters that you type are converted 
into a secure string and then saved in the $secure variable.

The second command displays the contents of the $secure variable. Because the $secure variable contains a secure string, Windows PowerShell displays only the 
System.Security.SecureString type.

The third command uses the ConvertFrom-SecureString cmdlet to convert the secure string in the $secure variable into an encrypted standard string. It saves the result in the 
$encrypted variable. The fourth command displays the encrypted string in the value of the $encrypted variable.

The fifth command uses the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlet to convert the encrypted standard string in the $encrypted variable back into a secure string. It saves the result in 
the $secure2 variable. The sixth command displays the value of the $secure2 variable. The SecureString type indicates that the command was successful.
```

Comment: thank you for the reply what could be the encode for byte in power shell. I want to avoid power shell and do the same operation in java. can you help me with these details?

Comment: I've no idea about it but see if [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051713/convert-a-string-to-a-byte-array-in-powershell-version-2) can help